# Matlab script declaring Simulink model variables

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

I was given the following protected Simulink model:
[image: Simulink model]

It works manually (I click on "Run" on the Simulink GUI and it gives me the three outputs).
I am writing a script using the Matlab SIMSET tool to define the necessary variables and to call this model in order to run it:

```
Constant=43;
Constant1=43;
Constant2=43;
Constant7=43;
Constant10=43;
Constant11=43;

t_stop = 100;
T_s = t_stop/1000;
options = simset('solver', 'ode5', 'fixedstep', T_s);
sim('test_lau.slx',t_stop,options)
```

I know that the interfaces "EC" and "UL" each take for input a vector, but even if I define two vectors in my script, how do I assign them to "EC" and "UL"?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: EC and UL are just labels on unused ports for the main block, you would need to update the model so that they are actually  connected to some input

Comment: Thanks, indeed I was missing something, now it seems to work